# O Fragmento atualiza quando eu seto dados no Firebase

Tags: android, android-fragment, firebase

**Eu tenho 3 fragmentos dentro de um pager de exibição e, sempre que meu banco de dados altera, ele reinicia o fragmento.**

> Classe TabAdapterAnunciante

```
package com.example.fernandosilveira.findpromotion.Adapter;

/**
 * Created by Fernando Silveira on 08/03/2017.
 */


import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;

import com.example.fernandosilveira.findpromotion.Fragment.DestaquesFragment;
import com.example.fernandosilveira.findpromotion.Fragment.HistoricoFragment;
import com.example.fernandosilveira.findpromotion.Fragment.ProximosVoceFragment;


public class TabAdapterUsuario extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    private String[] tituloAbas = {"Categorias","Próximo a Você", "Histórico"};

    public TabAdapterUsuario(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position)
    {

        Fragment fragment = null;

        switch (position)
        {
            case 0:
                fragment = new DestaquesFragment();
                break;
            case 1:
                fragment = new ProximosVoceFragment();
                break;
            case 2:
                fragment = new HistoricoFragment();
                break;
        }

        return fragment;

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount()
    {
        return tituloAbas.length;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position)
    {
        return tituloAbas[position];
    }
}
```

> Classe que controla os 3 fragmentos

```
package com.example.fernandosilveira.findpromotion.Activity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.PersistableBundle;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.fernandosilveira.findpromotion.Adapter.TabAdapterAnunciante;
import com.example.fernandosilveira.findpromotion.Adapter.TabAdapterUsuario;
import com.example.fernandosilveira.findpromotion.Geofence.ServicoLocalCliente;
import com.example.fernandosilveira.findpromotion.R;
import com.example.fernandosilveira.findpromotion.helper.SlidingTabLayout;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

public class PainelControle extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener
{
    private FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    private DatabaseReference ref = database.getReference();
    private TextView txtnomepainel,txtemailNav,txtv;
    private ProgressBar progressBar;
    private SlidingTabLayout slidingTabLayout;
    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private TabAdapterAnunciante tabAdapterAnunciante;
    private  TabAdapterUsuario tabAdapterUsuario;
    private String nome = "";
    private String email = "";
    private String tipo="";
    private String telefone = "";
    private static final String TAG = PainelControle.class.getSimpleName();
    private int MULTIPLA_PERMISSÃO_PEDIDO_CODIGO = 1;
    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        Log.d("Sistema","onStart(); Painel controle");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        Log.d("Sistema","onStop(); Painel controle");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.d("Sistema","onCreate(); Painel controle");
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_painel_controle);
        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        View hView =  navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
        txtnomepainel = (TextView)hView.findViewById(R.id.txtNomePainel);
        txtemailNav = (TextView)hView.findViewById(R.id.txtEmailNav);
        txtv = (TextView)hView.findViewById(R.id.txtv);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar)hView.findViewById(R.id.prgbarnav);

        // configurar toolbar
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_principal);
        toolbar.setTitle("");
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        //configurar abas
        slidingTabLayout = (SlidingTabLayout) findViewById(R.id.stl_tabs);
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.vp_pagina);
        tabAdapterUsuario = new TabAdapterUsuario(getSupportFragmentManager());
        tabAdapterAnunciante = new TabAdapterAnunciante(getSupportFragmentManager());
        txtnomepainel.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        txtemailNav.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        txtv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        Bundle extra = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extra!= null)
        {
            nome = extra.getString("nome");
            email = extra.getString("email");
            tipo = extra.getString("tipo");
            telefone = extra.getString("telefone");
            txtemailNav.setText(email);
            txtnomepainel.setText(nome);
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            txtv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            txtemailNav.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            txtnomepainel.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        if (tipo.equals("anunciante"))
        {
            //stopService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ServicoLocalCliente.class));
            //  invocar menu
            navigationView.inflateMenu(R.menu.menu_anunciante);
            //invocar tab
            viewPager.setAdapter(tabAdapterAnunciante);
            //atribuir tab ao layout
            navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        }
        else if(tipo.equals("usuario"))
        {
            iniciarGeofenceService();
            //  invocar menu
            navigationView.inflateMenu(R.menu.menu_usuario);
            //invocar tab
            //viewPager.setAdapter(tabAdapterUsuario);
            viewPager.setAdapter(tabAdapterUsuario);
            //atribuir tab ao layout
            navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        }
        slidingTabLayout.setDistributeEvenly(true);
        slidingTabLayout.setSelectedIndicatorColors(ContextCompat.getColor(this,R.color.colorPrimaryDark));
        slidingTabLayout.setViewPager(viewPager);
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed()
    {
        Log.d("Sistema","onBackPressed(); Painel controle");
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START))
        {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else

        {

            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState, PersistableBundle outPersistentState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState, outPersistentState);
        Log.d("Sistema","onSaveInstanceState(); Painel controle");
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        Log.d("Sistema","onConfigurationChanged(); Painel controle");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        Log.d("Sistema","onRestoreInstanceState(); Painel controle");
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.minhaconta)
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(PainelControle.this, MinhaConta.class);
            intent.putExtra("nome",nome);
            intent.putExtra("email",email);
            intent.putExtra("telefone",telefone);
            intent.putExtra("tipo",tipo);
            startActivity(intent);

        } else if (id == R.id.listadedesejos)
        {
            startActivity(new Intent(PainelControle.this, ListaDesejos.class));
        } else if (id == R.id.faleconosco)
        {
            startActivity(new Intent(PainelControle.this, FaleConosco.class));
        } else if (id == R.id.sobre)
        {
            startActivity(new Intent(PainelControle.this, Sobre.class));
        } else if (id == R.id.termosdeuso)
        {
            startActivity(new Intent(PainelControle.this, TermosUso.class));
        }else if (id == R.id.logout)
        {
            DeslogarUser();
        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }

    public void DeslogarUser()
    {
        //busca a instancia do usuario e desloga o usuario
        FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
        startActivity(new Intent(PainelControle.this, Login.class));
        stopService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ServicoLocalCliente.class));
        finish();
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.anim_fadein, R.anim.anim_fadeout);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Usuario Desconectado!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    private void iniciarGeofenceService() {

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ServicoLocalCliente.class);

        Log.i(TAG, "Início do serviço do cliente de localização");
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {

            boolean hasPermissionAccesssFineLocation = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(),
                    android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
            boolean hasPermissionAccesssCoarseLocation = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(),
                    android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
            if (!hasPermissionAccesssFineLocation || !hasPermissionAccesssCoarseLocation)
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
                        android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, MULTIPLA_PERMISSÃO_PEDIDO_CODIGO);
            else
                startService(intent);
        } else {

            startService(intent);
        }


    }

}
```

> Um dos Fragmentos

```
package com.example.fernandosilveira.findpromotion.Fragment;


import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AbsListView;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.CheckedTextView;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.example.fernandosilveira.findpromotion.Model.CategoriaProd;
import com.example.fernandosilveira.findpromotion.Model.Usuario;
import com.example.fernandosilveira.findpromotion.R;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class DestaquesFragment extends Fragment {
    private Usuario usuario;

    private ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter;
    private ListView listView;
    private CategoriaProd categoriaProd;
    private ArrayList<String> addDestaques = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<String> destaques = new ArrayList<>();

    private FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    private String meuUid;
    private ValueEventListener valueEventListener;
    private FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    private DatabaseReference ref = database.getReference();
    private SwipeRefreshLayout swrCat;


    public DestaquesFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        Log.d("Sistema","onStart(); DestaquesFragment");
        //ref.child("usuarios").child(meuUid).child("destaques").addValueEventListener(valueEventListener);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.d("Sistema","onCreateView(); DestaquesFragment");
        final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_destaques, container, false);
        listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listdestaq);
        atualizar();
        arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_checked ,destaques );
        listView.setChoiceMode(AbsListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
        listView.setAdapter( arrayAdapter );
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                CheckedTextView checkedTextView = (CheckedTextView) view;
                if (checkedTextView.isChecked()) {
                    addDestaques.add(destaques.get(position));
                    ref.child("usuarios").child(meuUid).child("destaques").setValue(addDestaques);
                } else {
                    addDestaques.remove(addDestaques.indexOf(destaques.get(position)));
                    ref.child("usuarios").child(meuUid).child("destaques").setValue(addDestaques);
                }
            }
        });

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        Log.d("Sistema","onStop(); DestaquesFragment");

    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        //ref.child("usuarios").child(meuUid).child("destaques").removeEventListener(valueEventListener);
        Log.d("Sistema","onPause(); DestaquesFragment");

    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Log.d("Sistema","onResume(); DestaquesFragment");
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        Log.d("Sistema","onConfigurationChanged(); DestaquesFragment");
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        Log.d("Sistema","onDetach(); DestaquesFragment");
    }

    public void atualizarLista()
    {
        destaques.clear();
        for (String ui: categoriaProd.todasSubCat)
        {destaques.add(ui);}
        for(String uid:destaques)
        {
            if(addDestaques.contains(uid)){
                listView.setItemChecked(destaques.indexOf(uid), true);
            } else {
                listView.setItemChecked(destaques.indexOf(uid), false);
            }
        }
    }
    public void atualizar()
    {
        if (user != null)
        {
           meuUid = user.getUid();
           ref.child("usuarios").child(meuUid).child("destaques").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
               @Override
               public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                   addDestaques.clear();
                   //Listar contatos
                   for (DataSnapshot dados : dataSnapshot.getChildren())
                   {addDestaques.add(dados.getValue().toString());}
                   atualizarLista();
               }
               @Override
               public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

               }
           });
        }
    }
    public void atualizarlista()
    {
        FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        if (user != null)
        {
            meuUid = user.getUid();
            valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    //Limpar lista
                    addDestaques.clear();
                    //Listar contatos
                    for (DataSnapshot dados : dataSnapshot.getChildren())
                    {addDestaques.add(dados.getValue().toString());}
                    atualizarLista();
                    arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                }
            };
        }

    }
}
```

> **Quando clico em um dos itens ele reinicia a activity principal e reinicia o fragmento,porém ele não retorna ao fragmento atual**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: Here are the categories]

Comment: Esse é o Stack Overflow em português, traduza sua dúvida ou publique-a na versão em [inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/)

Comment: Estranho esse comportamento de fechar e abrir o aplicativo, você deu uma olhada no LogCat para ver se aparece algo? Bote um ponto de Debug no seu OnItemClickListener da ListView e veja se ele entra no código.

Comment: Então,estava quebrando a cabeça com isso ,a unica solução que encontrei foi mudar o nó"destaques"  para o primeiro nó do banco...ai funcionou perfeitamente..não sei dizer a solução do problema